# Any way to play an "original" game of Civ 5

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I have the G+K expansion, but I like the old Piety tree better for happiness.  Also 2 out of 3 games I played I missed out on creating a religion.  Is there anyway to play Civ 5 original without uninstalling the expansion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable it by going to the main menu, clicking DLC and unticking G&K. It'll pretty much have the same effect as uninstalling it.

Comment: is it as simple as clicking it to turn it back on or does it have to re-install and download the files and such?

Comment: Unticking it does not delete any files.